# Reading from a particular fill till the last line in C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, eof, seekg

I have a text file with many lines. I want to store each line in a vector of strings. I want to read from the file until the last line is reached. I used the EOF function but it seems to store blank lines after the last line also. Here's a snippet of my code. text_list is a vector in which all the lines of the file are stored.

```
void TextBuddy::storeDataFromFileInVector(string filename){
ifstream infile;
int numbers;
string textMessage;
infile.open(filename);

while (!infile.eof()){
    getline(infile, textMessage);
    text_list.push_back(textMessage);
}
infile.close();
}
```

Comment: This has been repeated over and over: **Don't use `eof()` in a loop condition.** See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125 . (Instead you can use the return value of getline: _while (getline(infile, textMessage)) { text_list.push_back(textMessage); }_.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eof() does not look into the future. So, when you are right before EOF, you will read it also into your vector and probably corrupt it.

A better way to read all lines into a vector is:

```
string line;
while(getline(inFile, line)
    text_list.push_back(line);
```

Your loop will break once you've read an EOF or when any other error has occured.

Another method is using iterators and the algorithm library:

```
copy(istream_iterator<string>(inFile), istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter(text_list));
```

It's up to you which one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Blank lines, plural? You should check if it reached EOF before pushing to the list.

```
infile.open( filename );

getline( infile, textMessage );
while( !infile.eof() )
{
    text_list.push_back( textMessage );
    getline( infile, textMessage );
}
```

edit: KasF's answer is better.